# Exposing internals to a dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have an assembly which generates a helper assembly. And I want to expose internals of that assembly to the generated one.
But the generated assembly is in-memory assembly so it has random name everytime it is generated.
I do understand that I cannot use `InternalsVisibleTo()` in that case.
So I see two options:

1. There is another `InternalsVisibleTo` thing that I can use but I don't know about it's existance.
2. There is a way to delete assembly from HDD at least at app exit (I'll survive if it stay after exception) if I use `OutputAssembly` of `CompilerParameters` class to generate assembly with specific name. I think it cannot be done due the file is beeing used by the app.

May be some one can help me with that situation.

Comment: If you are using CodeDom to generate this in-memory assembly, you can set the `CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly` property to specify the generated assembly's name.

Comment: As you can see in my post I've already mentioned that possibility. The problem is that using CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly causes assembly file always being created.

Comment: Your item #2 does reference the use of OutputAssembly, but I found the verbage confusing and contradictory to what I have seen in the past.  The file is created, but it was not locked and can be deleted.  Admittedly, all my CodeDom work has been using the VB compiler and there may be some differences in execution, but I doubt that is the cause.  More likely, the cause in the setup of the compiler parameters and/or the instance creation and method execution.  Can you show that part of your code?

Comment: You are right. In fact that assembly isn't locked and can be deleted right after creation. This looks strange but it works. I hope MS won't change this behaviour. At least not in a wrong way.